# How to keep Prefix 0s for a real field in ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a real field in AX Table. When I save a number "099" its storing as "99". What properties I should change/ What I have to do to make sure that it saves it as "099" in the table instead of "99"? FYI: I want only real field in table not others like string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not generally possible in AX. It's not really possible in SQL either.

What you're talking about should most likely be a string with some custom logic.

If you want the field to always be a certain length and have the preceding zeros added, you could use a computed column, but there are limitations. See:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg845841.aspx
- https://stoneridgesoftware.com/using-computed-columns-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012/
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/how-do-i-preserve-the-leading-zeros-when-i-insert-a-number-into-this-table

Comment: Thanks for the info.